# How to add business keys/unique constraint in GraphQL - AppSync AWS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, graphql-js, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

Here is my definition of an entity/model in GraphQL SDL that is used by AWS Amplify to create an App Sync API and its table in DynamoDB.

I want to make the name and author as the business keys. Is there a way to achieve this?  I believe Prism has @Unique directive for the same. Or if it is not possible, can a constraint be added in the table in DynamoDB?

```js
type Post 
  @model 
  @versioned 
  @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) 
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  author: String!
  description: String
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by business keys? Primary/sort key?

Comment: @LisaMShon - In this case id is the Primary key. name and author together form the business key - meaning a post can be uniquely identified using the combination of name + author.

Comment: A post being uniquely identified sounds like a primary key. There is no concept of a `business key` in DyanmoDB. If you want the name + author combo to be the unique identifier of a post, then maybe you can set your ID as a name + author